# Interpretation of この人の家族『は』一体どんな気持ち『で』100万円出したんだ...?

Tags: grammar, translation, kanji, particles, interpretation

I would like to know if my analysis and interpretation is accurate or not.

> この人の家族『は』一体どんな気持ち『で』100万円出したんだ...?
> [Source](https://www.sukima.me/bv/t/blackjackniyoroshiku/v/1/s/3/p/18)

**Interpretation**

- この this → 人(person)の(possessive marker)家族(family)『は』(topic marker):
  *This person’s family is the topic of the sentence, what the sentence is about.*
- 一体(what the hell)どんな(what kind of)気持ち(feeling)『で』(manner of action):
  *How the heck do they feel (the family of the person)*
- 100万円(100x10,000 yen) 出した(to take out) んだ (casual of のだ, used for emphasis):
  *to have paid 100万円*.
- Full sentence:

  > How the hell does that person’s family feel about having paid 1000000 yen?

P.S.: Is there a difference between 気持**ち** and 気持? I have two separate entries in my dictionary but as far from I can tell they are identical.

Comment: Could you also include your final translation attempt (i.e., full sentence)? You seem to understand the meaning at the word level, but you may have failed to put them together...

Comment: Of course, I’ve edited my question with a full sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you understand the parts of the sentence very well.

The only thing that seems a little off about your translation is that it suggests the family is *retrospectively* thinking about having paid 100万円. But as you note, で marks a "manner of action", i.e. the part 一体どんな気持ちで is about how the family felt before or at the time of paying 100万円.

So I would say it should be more along the lines of

> - How in the world did [this person's] family feel when giving him 1,000,000 Yen?
> - In what kind of mindset / frame of mind must [this person's] family have been to pay 1,000,000 Yen?
> - etc.

There isn't enough context for a fitting translation, but お金を出す would be equally natural if that person had asked his family for money to pay off his gambling debts, for example.

P.S. 気持ち and 気持 are two different ways of writing the same word. In these kind of words *okurigana* are sometimes omitted, just as in 受付 v. 受け付け v. 受付け. (For these two words 気持ち and 受付 happen to be the most common spellings.)